# Problem with PHP Parse Cloud and Stripe when using Testing Credit Cards

Tags: php, node.js, parse-platform, stripe-payments, parse-cloud-code

Hope you can help me. I have a Parse Cloud function in Sashido (Parse Server) to manage a Stripe Subscription as following:

```
var stripe = require("stripe")("sk_test_CCCCccCCXXXXXXxXXX");
Parse.Cloud.define("crearCargo", function(request, response) {
    var  token = request.params.stripeToken;
    var  mail = request.params.email;
//var mail = request.params.email;

    //Crear Customer
    const customer = stripe.customers.create({
        email: mail,
        source: token,
    }, function(err, customer) {
        // asynchronously called
        if(err){
            response.error("Fallo Customer");
        }else{
           //const{id} = customer;
            id = customer.id;
            stripe.subscriptions.create({

                    customer: id,
                    items: [
                        {
                            plan: "plan_E0jrObw8X7Le2F",

                        },
                    ]
                }, function(err, subscription) {
                    if(err){
                        response.error(err.message);
                    }else{                        
                        response.success(subscription.id);
                    }
                }
            );
        }

    });

});
```

I call that function from my site via php like this:

```
$results = ParseCloud::run("crearCargo", ["stripeToken" => "$stripeToken", "email" => "$email"]);
```

This works fine when credit card is ok, but when I use a declined credit card to deal with the errors, I cant get error message in my php code, eventhough I see the error in the Log in Sashido dashboad. This is the log:

```
Failed running cloud function crearCargo for user undefined with:
  Input: {"stripeToken":"tok_1DaoDfHWMeJb0DRPDaAgN7rS","email":"shisuka11.08@gmail.com"}
  Error: {"code":141,"message":"Your card was declined."}
Nov 26, 2018, 12:50:44 -05:00 - ERROR
Error generating response for [POST] /1//functions/crearCargo 
"Your card was declined."

{
  "stripeToken": "tok_1DaoDfHWMeJb0DRPDaAgN7rS",
  "email": "myemail@email.com"
}
```

So I havent been able to deal with errors and instead I receeve a HTTP 500 ERROR in my browser, Do you have any clues why?

This is how a deal with the $result and works fine if credit card is valid, I do recieve the subscription code:

```
try {
    if(substr( $results, 0, 3 ) === "sub"){

       echo $results;

   }
} catch (ParseException $e) {
      echo 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
```

So when I use a 4242424242424242 credit card I do recieve subcription code, but when I force an error with credit card number 4100000000000019, I cant get error message back.

This is exactly what I received when I use PHP display error with ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Error recieved:

Fatal error: Uncaught Parse\ParseException: Your card was declined. in /home/u940759797/domains/powersellapp.com/public_html/web/Modelo/src/Parse/ParseClient.php:357 Stack trace: #0 /home/u940759797/domains/powersellapp.com/public_html/web/Modelo/src/Parse/ParseCloud.php(32): Parse\ParseClient::_request('POST', 'functions/crear...', NULL, '{"stripeToken":...', false) #1 /home/u940759797/domains/powersellapp.com/public_html/web/Modelo/suscripcion.php(28): Parse\ParseCloud::run('crearCargo', Array) #2 {main} thrown in /home/u940759797/domains/powersellapp.com/public_html/web/Modelo/src/Parse/ParseClient.php on line 357

Comment: If you instruct PHP to show detailed errors (`ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL); error_reporting(E_ALL);`
) what errors do you see on your php page when you try with an invalid card (4100000000000019, etc)

Comment: It shows me an Uncought Parse Exception with error code 141 and the error message Ivalid Credit Card. But I dont know how to catch it

Comment: I edited the questios, that is exactly what I recieved. any Ideas?

Comment: Try a simple `try { $results = ParseCloud::run(... your args ...); } catch(Exception $e) { print_r($e); }` does it echo out the exception?

Comment: Great duck, that was the thing!!!! Tnks bro...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is your `ParseCloud::run` call is not within your try-catch block. Try something like this:

```
try {
  $results = ParseCloud::run("crearCargo", ["stripeToken" => "$stripeToken", "email" => "$email"]);
} 
catch(ParseException $e) {
  echo 'Caught exception: '.$e->getMessage()."\n";
}
catch(Exception $e) {
  // do something with other exceptions, for testing we'll just print it out
  print_r($e);
}
```